# Revit API - Finding the path of nested links

Tags: revit-api

I am trying to find the file path of nested links and ran into a problem.
I am interested in the 2nd level, meaning finding the file path of a link inside one of the links in the file that I currently have opened.

My problem is where the reference Type is Overlay, if reference type is Attachment I don't have a problem.
I am also assuming the files are in BIM360 cloud, but I believe I have the same problem if the files were local.

I am able to get the RevitLinkInstance and RevitLinkType object for those links.
However, if I try to use GetLinkDocument() on the RevitLinkInstance I get null, and trying getting the InSessionPath using GetExternalResourceReferences() on the RevitLinkType get me "Autodesk Docs://" and stops there without the real path.

Will appreciate any help including letting me know if this is at all possible.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowlegde it is impossible to get the link within a link through one Document. This is because with Overlay the link is not stored into the Link. That is also why it works with Attachment. Because Revit than makes it a point to store the Link in that file and thus it is part of that Revit file.

What you could do instead is search for the file path of the first link. Then use the file path in the `OpenAndActivateDocument(string filepath)` method. Repeat the first step to get all RevitLinkInstances of this Document. You can get the needed information from this link, store it in a variable and close the link document.

If an example is needed please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, this work.

OpenAndActivateDocument(string filepath) didn't work for me on cloud models saying it couldn't find the file, not sure which path format it expects but the ones I tried didn't work.

I used OpenAndActivateDocument(modelPath, openOptions, detachAndPrompt) instead using GetLinkDocument() on the link instance and GetCloudModelPath() on the document and it works.

In order to close the document I needed to change the active document and the only way I found is using OpenAndActivateDocument() on the original active document.